# How to pass values instead of Vector in foreach loop?

Tags: scala, performance-testing, load-testing, gatling

My Reponse is:

```
[
{"id":106455,"assetId":482282,"masterKeyframeId":157060,"closed":false},
{"id":106661,"assetId":502174,"masterKeyframeId":169193,"closed":false}
{.....and so many...}
]
```

I have fetched "assetId" and "masterKeyframeId" correctly using below request, but the problem is how do I set both values in foreach loop? (I have used "aid" and it fetches single value but don't know about passing single value for "mkeyframeId" as it takes Vector)

```
.exec(http("request_7")
            .get(uri3 + "/sortBy=SEGGREGATED_SESSION_SORT;reviewState=IN_PROGRESS")
            .check(jsonPath("$..assetId").findAll.saveAs("astId"))
            .check(jsonPath("$..masterKeyframeId").findAll.saveAs("mkeyframeId"))
            .headers(headers_7)
            )

        .foreach("${astId}", "aid") {
            doIf(session => session("aid").as[String] != "-1")
            {
                exec(http("Set_IDs")
                .get("/a/" + accountname + "/assets/${aid}/keyframe/${mkeyframeId}")
                )
            }
        }
```

Here the problem is `${mkeyframeId}` it takes vector and pass in url like this,
    Sending request=Set_IDs uri=`https://qa1.net/a/hbmin1ac/assets/482282/keyframe/Vector(157060,%20169193):`

Instead of

```
https://qa1.net/a/hbmin1ac/assets/482282/keyframe/157060
https://qa1.net/a/hbmin1ac/assets/502174/keyframe/169193
```

Thanks.

Comment: `get("/a/" + accountname + "/assets/${aid}/keyframe/${mkeyframeId(0)}")` Keep in mind that it can throw a `IndexOutOfBoundException`, if `mkeyframeId` was an `empty` vector.

Comment: Thanks Sarvesh. Please post your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should try something like this:

```
.foreach("${astId}", "aid", "counter") {
  doIf { session =>
    for {
      aid <- session("aid").validate[String]
    } yield aid != "-1"
  } {
    exec(http("Set_IDs")
      .get { session =>
        for {
          aid <- session("aid").validate[String]
          mkeyframeId <- session("mkeyframeId").validate[Seq[String]]
          c <- session("counter").validate[Int]
        } yield  s"/a/$accountname/assets/$aid/keyframe/${mkeyframeId(c)}"
      }
    )
  }
}
```

You can write the doIf block like this too:

```
doIf( _("aid").validate[String].map(_ != "-1"))
```